# How to shift the rows in a 4x5 matrix left by 2 elements

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

> Given an array p[5], write a function to shift it circularly left by two positions. Thus, if p[0] = 15, p[1]= 30, p[2] = 28, p[3]= 19 and p[4] = 61 then after the shift p[0] = 28, p[1] = 19, p[2] = 61, p[3] = 15 and p[4] = 30. Call this function for a (4 x 5 ) matrix and get its rows left shifted by 2.

Below is the code I have for it so far, but it isn't working. The problem with is is that since the helper function takes a parameter `int *`, it doesn't take the array in the main function, therefore it doesn't do it right. It compiles fine though.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void moveLeft2(int p[5])
{
    int temp1 = p[0];
    int temp2 = p[1];

    for(int i = 0; i <  5 - 2; i++)
    {
        p[i] = p[i + 2];
    }

    p[3] = temp1;
    p[4] = temp2;
}

int main()
{
    int p[4][5] = {
        {15,30,28,19,61},
        {1,2,3,4,5},
        {6,7,8,9,20},
        {11,12,13,14,15}};
    int i;

    moveLeft2(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: What is the problem with it? Compile error? what is in the array? Define the problem.

Comment: You have a function to shift/rotate one row. Loop over the rows and shift each on its own.

Comment: The problem with is is that since the helper function takes a parameter int *, it doesn't take the array in the main function, therefore it doesn't do it right. It compiles fine though.

Comment: `p[0]` is an array of 5 `int`, passing `p[0]` to `moveLeft2()` is correct and will rotate the first row of the matrix 2 positions to the left. Proceed with the remaining rows in a loop.

Answer (score 3):

You might have faced this question in the Exercise of the book, Let Us C, by Yashwant Kanetkar.

Let me revise the question,
**Given an array p[ 5 ], write a function to shift it circularly left by two positions. Thus, if p[ 0 ] = 15, p[ 1 ]= 30, p[ 2 ] = 28, p[ 3 ]= 19 and p[ 4 ] = 61 then after the shift p[ 0 ] = 28, p[ 1 ] = 19, p[ 2 ] = 61, p[ 3 ] = 15 and p[ 4 ] = 30. Call this function for a (4 x 5 ) matrix and get its rows left shifted.**

So, the half part of the question is easy and you may have solved it. Let me give you a solution applicable for complete question:

The logic is to pass base address of the array to the function, and using this address only, we would access to the other elements of the array as;

```
   temp1 = *p;
   temp2 = *(p+1);
   for(i=0;i<n-2;i++){
      *(p+i) = *(p+i+2);
   }
    *(p+n-2)=temp1;
    *(p+n-1)=temp2;
```

Now, doing the same thing for multiple 1-D arrays, we could pass the base address of  each array to the function from main by caling the funtion iteratively, as;

```
   for(i=0;i<4;i++)
   shift(ar[i], 5);
```

But, this logic has some limitations :

- We must know array dimentions in advance.
- Same can not be extended for any 2-d Arrays.
- We have to call the function iteratively from main funtion, passing the base address of each 1-D array.

  By using the property of array that all the elements are in consecutive memory locations, we could write a simple solution overcoming all these limitations...
  We can access to base address of next 1-D array by increment of the pointer to the previous array by the number of elements in the array:

  p = p + 5;

Now, we can pass this address to the function for shifting the elements of nect 1-D array. 
Doing this recursively until there exist any 1-D array would result in shifting all the rows of the given array.

```
  if(*p)
  shift(p, n);
```

So, finally, following is a complete program implementing the same logic explained here. This program shows that the same fuction will work for shifting both 1-D and 2-D arrays;

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   void shift(int *p, int n){
     int i, temp1, temp2;
     temp1 = *p;
     temp2 = *(p+1);
     for(i=0;i<n-2;i++){
         *(p+i) = *(p+i+2);
     }
     *(p+n-2)=temp1;
     *(p+n-1)=temp2;

     p = p + 5;
     if(*p)
         shift(p, n);
   }

    int main(){
     int arr[5] = {15, 30, 28, 19, 61};
     int ar[4][5]={
        {1,2,3,4,5},
        {11,12,13,14,15},
        {21,22,23,24,25},
        {31,32,33,34,35}
      };
     register int i, j;

     shift(arr, 5);

     for(i=0;i<5;i++)
     printf("%d ", arr[i]);
     printf("\n");

     shift(ar[0], 5);

     for(i=0;i<4;i++){
         for(j=0;j<5;j++)
         printf("%d ", ar[i][j]);
      printf("\n");
     }
     return 0;
   }
```

Output :

```
28 19 61 15 30 
3 4 5 1 2
13 14 15 11 12
23 24 25 21 22
33 34 35 31 32
```

Comment: I'm afraid your post does not help: why make `shift()` a recursive function and use a bogus terminating test that will fail and cause undefined behavior.  There is no null terminator at the end of an `int` array, only C strings have this feature.

Comment: You are absoltutely correct @chqrlie but the terminating test case would always work as it is just checking if there is any element decleared/defined at the given memory location. Moreover, for n*m matrix, as numer of interations are not known, calling a function recursive until all the operations are done is the only best solution

Comment: I'm afraid you are incorrect: in the call `shift(arr, 5)`, `shift` will read the value of `arr[5]`, which has undefined behavior. Reading beyond the end of the array may produce a zero or non zero value or have untold side effects such as a segmentation fault. Your approach cannot work even for the matrix case: why should `shift` stop if a matrix row happens to start with a `0`? and in this particular test, `shift` will again read beyond the end of the matrix causing undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
void moveLeft2(int p[5])
```

That declaration is actually a lie. What it means is

```
void moveLeft2(int *p)
```

i.e. the argument passed to `moveLeft2` shall be a pointer to `int`. The implementation assumes that the pointer points to a block of memory large enough to hold five `int`s, which is not enforced by the type and thus unsafe, but the important point here is that the function argument must have type `int*`.

And if you have

```
int row[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
moveLeft2(row);
```

the compiler will not emit a warning, even at the highest warning level. That is because arrays are converted to pointers to their first element when they are passed to functions (and in most other contexts; arrays are **not** converted to pointers to their first element as the argument of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof` and `&` [address] operators). So the passed argument has exactly the required type.

The declaration

```
int p[4][5] = {...};
```

declares `p` as an array of 4 arrays of 5 `int`s each. `p[0]` is the first of these `int[5]`, so

```
moveLeft2(p[0]);
```

is a type-correct function call (the array `p[0]` is converted to a pointer to its first element, which is `&p[0][0]`). The array `p[0]` is an array of five `int`s, so the assumption in the implementation of `moveLeft2` is satisfied, and the call is not only type-correct, but also semantically correct.

The same holds for the other rows of the array (of arrays) `p`, hence

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    moveLeft2(p[i]);
}
```

shifts all four rows, one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

**Replacements:**

- `void moveLeft2(int p[5])` with `void moveLeft2(int *p)`
- `moveLeft2(p);` with `moveLeft2(p[i]);`
- Add `for (i = 0; i < 4; i ++)` before `moveLeft2(p[i]);`

**Code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>

void moveLeft2(int *p)
{
    int temp1 = p[0];
    int temp2 = p[1];
    int i;



    for(i = 0; i <  5 - 2; i++)
    {
        p[i] = p[i + 2];
    }

    p[3] = temp1;
    p[4] = temp2;
}

int main()
{
    int p[4][5] = {
        {15,30,28,19,61},
        {1,2,3,4,5},
        {6,7,8,9,20},
        {11,12,13,14,15}};
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i ++)
        moveLeft2(p[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to write is a loop calling `moveLeft2` for each row in the matrix:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void moveLeft2(int p[5]) {
    int temp1 = p[0];
    int temp2 = p[1];

    for (int i = 0; i <  5 - 2; i++) {
        p[i] = p[i + 2];
    }
    p[3] = temp1;
    p[4] = temp2;
}

int main() {
    int p[4][5] = {
        { 15, 30, 28, 19, 61 },
        {  1,  2,  3,  4,  5 },
        {  6,  7,  8,  9, 20 },
        { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 },
    };
    int rows = sizeof(p) / sizeof(p[0]);
    int cols = sizeof(p[0]) / sizeof(p[0][0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        moveLeft2(p[i]);
    }
    // output the matrix:
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            printf("%3d ", p[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 28  19  61  15  30
  3   4   5   1   2
  8   9  20   6   7
 13  14  15  11  12
```

Note however that it would be more consistent to pass `cols` to the rotating function and to name the function `rotateLeft2`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void rotateLeft2(int *p, int cols) {
    if (cols > 2) {
        int temp1 = p[0];
        int temp2 = p[1];
        for (int i = 0; i < cols - 2; i++) {
            p[i] = p[i + 2];
        }
        p[cols - 2] = temp1;
        p[cols - 1] = temp2;
    }
}

int main() {
    int p[][5] = {
        { 15, 30, 28, 19, 61 },
        {  1,  2,  3,  4,  5 },
        {  6,  7,  8,  9, 20 },
        { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 },
    };
    // compute the matrix dimensions at compile time
    int rows = sizeof(p) / sizeof(p[0]);
    int cols = sizeof(p[0]) / sizeof(p[0][0]);

    // rotate the matrix rows:
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        rotateLeft2(p[i], cols);
    }
    // output the matrix:
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            printf("%3d ", p[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```